# Loud notification(?) sound happens at random on LG Stylo 6

Tags: notifications, lg-g-stylo

This was my mom's phone, she got a new one and I inherited this nearly brand new stylo. I factory reset the phone (mainly to get rid of her dozens of unwanted apps), and found that when I unplugged the phone, it would make this really annoying loud sound:

Low-pitched tone for .5 sec, high-pitched tone for .5 sec, then a long slide from low register to high register. Reminiscent of a car alarm, kind of.

I have used Macrodroid on my old Stylo 3 for various utilities, so I downloaded it and made a Macro that detects unplugging of phone, turns on "Do Not Disturb," waits 2 seconds, then turns off "Do Not Disturb." This fixed the beep when I unplug my phone, but...

Now, this nasty, loud beepy thing happens at random. I'll be at the store, or in my garage, or it's sitting on my desk charging, etc. etc, and BAM! low beep, high beep, low to high swoop. My brother just now was two rooms over and came in to ask me, "So, was that your phone making that crazy sound again?" I told him "Yes, it just happens randomly now."

WTF?!? Any ideas on what could be causing this? I went through my notification sounds, and can't find one that sounds like that, I made sure that my NFC was turned off (I read that sometimes that can pick up a signal and do weird things).

Comment: Hi, could you record the audio and share it here? ([Vocaroo](https://vocaroo.com/), [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/), or anything else)